# No connection only in terminal

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm beginer and I try to use Fedora 23 in VirtualBox. I have an access to the Internet using Firefox browser.

But when I try to do something in Terminal (like: `sudo dnf update`) I have an error:

`Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64' : Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=x86_64 [Connection timed out after 120002 milliseconds]`

I can open the link using Firefox browser.

Comment: Are you using Firefox on the same VM where you are trying to run `sudo dnf update`? Accessing the internet on your physical machine does not imply you have connection on your VM.

Comment: Run the following on your terminal console:

`nc mirrors.fedoraproject.org 443` and then `echo $?`. The first command will try to create a connection on the HTTPS port. The second command will show you the result of the first command. If the second command issues anything different from 0, it is an error.

Comment: Yes, I use Firefox under this Fedora system when I try to call `dnf update`. I had to set proxy and I can open http and https links in the browser.

Comment: Then the problem is the proxy on the way. Setting a proxy on Firefox will not set the proxy for your entire system.

Comment: `nc mirrors.fedoraproject.org 443` does not work. The same issue.

Comment: So where I have to set this? I did it using system Settings -> Network proxy and I set HTTP Proxy and HTTPS proxy.

Comment: Cool. Then you need to set the proxy for `dnf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually how to let dnf access mirrors.fedoraproject.org via HTTPS with a proxy. [This guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-dnf-command-with-a-proxy-server-on-fedora/) will solve the issue.

Since you are a beginner, I would recommend using pico or nano instead of vi. They are more user friendly for beginners. You just press Control+X to leave the editor, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use other console programs accessing the web, set your proxies with (adapt IP address and port):

```
 export http_proxy=http://10.0.0.12:8080/
 export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

You can save these into your home directory in `.bash_profile` to make the change permanent.